# Reloading of page after redirect() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my example I click on an object in browser view and it gets deleted from **myArray**.
The deleting process works fine. Please see console.log-Output.

After POST request server redirects browser to '/'. Here I would expect the browser reloading the page.
I added a possible *client side solution* (please see "template.html") by adding **window.location.reload()** to the fetch command.
Anyhow this is not a satisfying way to do it. Does somebody know how to force refreshing page by node.js server in "app.js"?
In the chrome developer tools I saw the GET request by redirect is successfully carried out. I think the reason why the page does not change is because the browser detects that he is already on correct path '/'. Therefore he sees no reason to refresh page.

```js
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const myModule = require('myModule');

app.use(express.json());

var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = {"name":"Object0"};
myArray[1] = {"name":"Object1"};
myArray[2] = {"name":"Object2"};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(myArray);
    var htmlTemplate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/template.html', 'utf-8');
    htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replace("{$content$}", myModule.returnContent(myArray));
    res.send(htmlTemplate);
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    myArray.splice(req.body.id, 1);
    res.redirect('/');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

```js
//myModule.js
exports.returnContent = function(array){
    let myText = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
        myText += '<p id="';
        myText += i;
        myText += '">'
        myText +=array[i].name;
        myText +="</p>";
    }
    return myText;
}
```

```html
<!-- template.html -->
{$content$}
<script>
    var pElementArray = document.querySelectorAll("p");
        pElementArray.forEach((item) => {item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            const id = item.id;
            fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({id: id})})
        })
        })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using fetch request like a `rest api`, its logical that your frontend is not getting connected with backend, so you need to navigate manually

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    myArray.splice(req.body.id, 1);
    const redirectUrl = '/';
    // Sending the URL to redirect to as part of the JSON response
    res.json({ redirectUrl });
});
```

```
fetch('/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({id: id})}).then((response) => {
       return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
       // change the url
       window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
  })
```

Comment: Many thanks to your answer, it gave me valueable input